# Remove single quotes from Javascript object keys

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have the key of the object not be surrounded by single quotes.

```
let arr= [2, 3, 4, 11];
let myObj={};
myObj[arr[2]]=true;
console.log(myObj);
```

The above code outputs the result **{ '4': true }**

How do I remove the single quotes around 4 and have it display as **{ 4: true }**

Comment: well, `{ '4': true }` and `{ 4: true }` is the same thing. it doesn't make your code run differently.

Comment: Object keys in Javascript are always strings. Please explain what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @Layhout : But is there a way to remove the quotes if I needed to? I just don't want a number to be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 11];
const myObj = {};
myObj[arr[2]] = true;
const str = JSON.stringify(myObj);
console.log(str.replace(/[",']/g, ''));
```